# How do I create classes that represent complex xml tag structures in google-api-java-client

Tags: google-api-java-client

Using the google-api-java-client I have gathered that the library parses the xml based on the classes you create and the keys you make. For example: if you have the following XML:

```
<entry test="ok">
<link name="somewhere.org"/>
</entry>
```

Then you could have these two classes:

```
public class Entry
{
  @Key("@test")
  public String test;

  @Key("link")
  public Link link;
}

public class Link
{
  @Key("name")
  public String name;
}
```

And the library would parse the xml and create the appropriate classes (if I understand it correctly)

If that is the case, how does one represent an xml tag that has both attributes and a value? Example:

```
<entry test="ok">
    <link name="somewhere.org">SomeValue</link>
</entry>
```

In particular I'm trying to represent a record such as the following so I can insert it into a google docs spreadsheet:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:gs="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006">
  <title>Darcy</title>
  <gs:field name='Birthday'>2/10/1785</gs:field>
  <gs:field name='Age'>28</gs:field>
  <gs:field name='Name'>Darcy</gs:field>
  <gs:field name='CanVote'>No</gs:field>
</entry>
```

Also, where is this documented? I can't find the documentation but perhaps I'm just not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best documentation for the XML data model in the [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) library is the [XML JavaDoc](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.1.1-alpha/com/google/api/client/googleapis/xml/atom/package-summary.html).

The @Key annotation to use with the name attribute is "@name".  So you are only missing one character :)

```
public class Link
{
  @Key("@name")
  public String name;
}
```

See an example of the [Link](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-oauth-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/calendar/v2/model/Link.java?repo=samples) class in the [calendar-v2-atom-oauth-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-oauth-sample/instructions.html?r=default).

Full disclosure: I'm an owner of the google-api-java-client project.

Comment: Ah, that documentation link was very helpful. If I understand it correctly then to get the attribute name you would use @key("@name") and then to get the textual value of the link tag, ('SomeValue' above) then you would use the syntax @Key("text()"). Is that correct? Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: Right that's the idea.  By the way: @Key String name is short for @Key("name") String name.